# Java client and Java EE server communication

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, architecture, jax-rs, jax-ws

I have an architectural question. I want a Java client to communicate with a Java EE server (Glassfish). I don't want to use remote EJB invocations and use GlassFish Application Client Container, I need something more lightweight. So I consider calls over HTTP.

RESTful seems to me the easiest way from the technical point of view. But I'm confused about architectural style. I mean, I'm NOT creating a system that is defined in terms of 'resources', but in terms of 'methods'. So JAX-WS may be appropriate, but I would prefer to transfer not only XML, but just raw data in HTTP message body.

Should I consider servlets or something else? What is the best practices for client-server communication?

Answer (score 1):

> raw data in http message body

What kind of raw data, like bytes encoded in base64? That doesn't really sound like the typical job for HTTP. Somewhere in between EJB and Webservices there are other solutions that may fit better and can be faster. For example messaging/serialization frameworks like Apache Thrift or Protocol Buffers.

Anyways, if you go the HTTP way:

Sometimes it's possible to model method-like endpoints as resources, but doesn't always work. If there are no resources, just call it a "Web API" and only keep RESTful concepts and best practices that make sense for you. Caching, nice URLs and leveraging HTTP status codes and header for example.

JAX-WS isn't limited to transferring XML. It it's based on WSDLs though, which you might not need. REST API are easier to handle and more flexible.

JAX-RS is a good choice to build any kind of non-WSDL Web APIs. It provides a clean API and a lot useful features, even if you only use it for simple GET/POST operations.

Comment: *"If there are no resources, just call it a "Web API" and only keep RESTful concepts and best practices that make sense for you".* +1 for that statement alone. People tend to focus too much on doing REST  when other solutions exist that are easier to build, understand, and maintain.

Comment: @Bogdan Yeah, it's like no one dares to make something that is not REST anymore ... or they will call it RESTful anyway, just because it has cool URIs. I really hope hypermedia APIs / semantic web services would get more traction, I feel like they are the only things that could end this resource-based madness.